# jQuery AJAX blob response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, blob

I am working on an mobile App and have some issues with the jQuery AJAX `get` method. I want to receive a video from my server, but somehow I can't receive the *file* in the format I want.

Here is my code (receiving the data as blob and everything):

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'MyServerAddress/testVideos/test.mp4', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var video = document.createElement('video');
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
                video.autoplay = true;
                document.body.appendChild(video);
            }else{
                "CORS failed. Check Internet Connection."
            }
};
xhr.send();
```

But unfortunately this code doesn't run on mobile devices.

The jQuery Ajax:

```
 jQuery.ajaxSetup({
             async:false,
             dataType:'blob'
 });

 $.get("MyServerAddress/testVideos/test.mp4",function(d){
             var video = document.createElement('video');
             video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(d);
             video.autoplay = true;
             document.body.appendChild(video);
 }).error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(ajaxOptions);
            console.log(thrownError);
 });
```

When I run the jQuery code I get the following error:

> parser error (index):67 No conversion from text to blob"

Because the transmitted data isn't of the type *blob*.

Is there any possibility to send the data from jQuery directly as *blob*? If yes, how? And is there a way to make the code above work on mobile devices too?

Thank you very much,
SirSandmann

Comment: Take a look at the following article for a possible solution: http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: It's working with desktop fine, but mobile still not. I have no clue why.